# Can a finite automaton have more than one regular expression?

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

A finite automaton is a generator for a regular language, and a regular expression represents a regular language. A language can be represented in many forms of regular expressions.
So can a finite automaton have more than one regular expression?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the meaning of "a finite automaton having (one or more) regular expressions"?

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways of writing the same expression, then I guess yes, it can be represented by many expressions.

For example, look at this DFA (with the initial state being final)

```
-->(a)________
    ^         |
    |         |
    |         V
    '--------(b)
```

the regular expression for it can take infinite forms, such as

$(ab)^*\;$ or $\;(ab)^*(ab)^*\;$ or $\;(ab)^*(ab)^*(ab)^*\;$ ...

If you consider different forms of the same expression, then it can be represented by lots of regexs, otherwise is just 1.

Answer (score 2):

Every regular expression is equivalent to infinitely many other regular expressions. Indeed, the regular expression $r$ is completely equivalent to the regular expressions $r+r,r+r+r,\ldots$, for example.